# Shell script, if statement to check value of environment variable

Tags: shell, environment-variables

I have a shell script that needs changing so as to only work when the value of an environment variable is `true`. The variable will come from Heroku, if that matters.

My script looks like:

```
if [[ $SANDBOX_SITE = "true" ]]
then
    *run existing script*
else 
    exit
fi
```

I can see the environment variable is present with `printenv` and I run the script through `heroku run bash --app *appname*` so I know it's in the right shell.
Any tips or advice would be appreciated.

*edit 
I forgot to add, the script exits everytime.

Comment: What happens when you execute this script?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It exits everytime. I've also placed some `echo` in each part of the if and it is definitely exiting even with the variable present on heroku.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have forgotten to export the environment variable. The environment variable may exist in current shell, but won't be available to child shell if it is not exported. Use:

```
export SANDBOX_SITE="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Heroku but a quick glance at the documentation implies you need to explicitly set the desired env vars. For example, `heroku run bash --env SANDBOX_SITE=$SANDBOX_SITE --app appname`. Or, possibly via the `heroku config:set` command.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-run